# React Native - App Registry not registered module and Undefined NavigationTabs Error - Top Navigator Tutorial

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, routes, navigator

Hello I tried following this tutorial (
https://www.javatpoint.com/react-native-create-material-top-tab-navigator)
to create a top tab navigator but I am getting these errors.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _reactNavigationTabs.default)...')
```

And

```
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

I have tried restarting and my emulator, and changing the import statements but still no luck.
I tried searching for solutions online but the errors are still there.

I am a complete beginner, please help? I am running an android emulator and using vs code.

Comment: You probably don't have all the dependencies installed, read the documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/.

Comment: thanks I think it was setup issues